# Typescript object inside object in angular model error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created below class as a model in angular

```
export class Product {
    constructor(private name: string, private data: { price: number, discount: number }) { }
}
```

and creating its instance in component like this:

```
product: Product = new Product("abc", { 10, 2});
```

but typescript compiling fails like this:

```
Error: src/app/home/home.component.ts:11:48 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

11   product: Product = new Product("abc", { 10, 2});
                                                  ~




× Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide an object by specifying the property name.

```js
product: Product = new Product("abc", { price: 10, discount: 2 });
```